# When I change the ads:adUnitId to my own string id the ad is not shown

Tags: android, admob

I'm having some problems with admob, when I create a activity using admob it works normally but just when I use the **ads:adUnitId** of test, when I change this id to my id created on admob page, doesn't not show anything more.

I had thought it was some kind of delay of admob page to register this new id, but it's been 3 days ago and nothing. Anyone has any idea where can be the error, cause the project works with id of test, and I already tried created 4 new ads on admob page but any id works.

Other doubt is, when I have more than one activity that show the banner, I have to create more than one ad block on admob page, right? And in every ads:adUnitId I have to inform this new string id? What happen if I use just one id to the whole project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand the error use the admob banner callback particularly this one:

```
@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
}
```

Log the errorCode from the callback and check this out to understand what is the error ([ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/ad-events)):

> onAdFailedToLoad()

The onAdFailedToLoad() method is the only one that includes a parameter. The errorCode parameter indicates what type of failure occurred. The possible values are defined as constants in the AdRequest class:

ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR
Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.

ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST
The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.

ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR
The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.

ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL
The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

**REGARDING YOUR SECOND QUESTION** its possible to display same banner id on two diferent screens

Comment: Hi, really thanks, I did what you said and return the constant value 1, and according to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest, it's `"ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST

The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.

Constant Value: 1"`, you have any idea what could be happening? 'cause I'm new on this, and I'm a little lost... :( 
Note - I read some about google-services.json, this is necessary? 'cause without this the banner works too, but also just the test id one

Comment: Double check the ad unit id you are setting in the id property. This error indicate a problem in the ad unit. Also make sure the app package defined in admob dashboard is the same as in your app. Dont mix developer and ad unit id

Comment: Yeah, you right, I was confusing id of app with id of ad, I put the right now (id of ad), but however now the error code is 2 (like if internet is turned off, and it isn't), I can see also that even with the test id (when ad is shown) always return the error code 0. You said something about package of app, but I didn't see any space to put it, it just is request when I wanna to integrate Firebase, right? And this interaction is not obligatory, right?

Comment: @Anita look at this in admob dashboard http://prntscr.com/eal0kr   when you want to monetize an app you need to supply its store listing or package name that way admob knows that you are calling ads from the right app. about false error code 2 try to uninstall the app and install again then re check it

Comment: OMG I was thinking that space was to put the app name (by which it is called) and not the package name, silly me. By the way this silly mistake works sometimes, sometimes the ad is shown, go figure! Can I do the one last question the last I swear ;) is  that I also have a channel in YouTube with ads too you know to say if I have both mobile and channel ads in the same email adress then the adsense and admob money will be added or I will receive them in separate? And if in admob case if I use the same unitId to all ads in a same app this way I'll reach faster the 1000 impression? Thanks so much

Comment: @Anita On the admob dashboard you do fill the app name, just make sure that the app pointed in dashboard package is the same as the app you are trying to show ads in. The payment should receive separately youtube and admob are different services. It doesn't matter if you reach 1000 impressions from one ad unit or few. If I helped you solve your problem please mark my answer as correct. thanks